# Add if statement to Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that needs to return a single row if there are `more than 2` rows with a certain `ID.` I figured the best way to do this was to add a counter in my query to count the instances of `x` and then return the results `if x >=2` but I'm not sure how in `Oracle`.

My query now returns all of the instances of `x` in all `playlists`. I need it to return the playlist only if it has more than 2 instances of `x`

```
Select * from PLAYLIST p
left join PLAYLIST_SONGS ps on p.PLAYLIST_ID = ps.PLAYLIST_ID
join SONG s on ps.SONG_ID = s.SONG_ID
join Artists art on s.ARTIST_ID = art.ARTIST_ID
where art.BAND='x'
and p.NUM_SONGS >=2;
```

Comment: are you using mysql or oracle or both?

Comment: Read up on the `Having` clause which is an extended where clause that is applied after aggregates have been determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the playlists with 2 or more songs of a certain artist, something like this might help you out:

```
SELECT *
FROM playlist p
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)
       FROM playlist_songs ps JOIN song s ON ps.song_id = s.song_id
       JOIN artists art ON s.artist_id = art.artist_id
       WHERE ps.playlist_id = p.playlist_id
       AND art.band = 'X') >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the concept of having and a group by to get songs with count > 1.  Note field 1,2,3,4 in this case must not cause the records you want to combine to be unique.  Otherwise, pablomatico's approach could work

```
Select Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
from PLAYLIST p
left join PLAYLIST_SONGS ps on p.PLAYLIST_ID = ps.PLAYLIST_ID
join SONG s on ps.SONG_ID = s.SONG_ID
join Artists art on s.ARTIST_ID = art.ARTIST_ID
where art.BAND='x'
GROUP BY Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
HAVING count(PS.Song_ID)  >=2
```

You could also use an analytic function (window function) such as over partition by assign a row number to each song.  something like row_number() over (partition by song_Id)

Answer (score 0):

One other solution would be to use an inline correlated view to also get the number of songs:

```
select 
    p.*,
    (
      select 
          count(distinct s.song_id) 
        from 
          playlist_songs ps
          join songs s on s.song_id = ps.song_id
          join artists art on s.artist_id = art.artist_id
        where p.playlist_id = ps.playlist_id
    ) number_of_songs 
  from 
    playlist p
  where 
    number_of_songs > 1;
```